# Using Squid to append text to HTTP responses on demand

Tags: http, proxy, squid

I am trying to setup a http proxy, but sadly I don't really know what I'm doing.

The primary function of this proxy will be to append a javascript file to the bottom of any web request if a certain parameter is present in the Query String.

For example, if I had Firefox setup to go through the proxy, if i went to http://www.anypage.com/?enable_script=true the following line would be present at the bottom of the source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/script.js"></script>
```

I have played aroudn with Squid a little, it appears to be able to do what I need but documentation is limited and I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: did u get this working?? As i need the same...

Answer (score 2):

You should start by reading http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation

Comment: I have, and read the Client Streams and eCAP documentation, but I couldn't find many relevant examples and I don't really know where to start.

Comment: There is code for eCap modifying adapter available on http://www.e-cap.org/Downloads. Link to this site available on page I've mentioned above.